# How can I force-disable all dock detection/HDMI connectivity?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, hardware, motorola-droid-razr, hdmi, docking-station

**Context:**

I have a RAZR MAXX XT912 with 4.1.2 (3.0.8-gbacb1cf). As soon as I wake it for any reason, it immediately acts as if it is connected via HDMI, despite the fact that no cable is connected.

Many people have this problem, and it is usually a result of a software issue or a shorted connection somewhere in the HDMI hardware/plug that results in a phone thinking it is docked.

For me, it occurs constantly (some people experience it intermittently)--as soon as I wake the phone from sleep/non-lit states, it immediately rotation-locks itself into widescreen and presents me with the docking choices menu.

**Question:**

Is there some way to permanently disable HDMI dock detection?

**What I've tried:**

- I've tried the "HDMI Connection" setting; whenever I uncheck it, the phone goes back to normal. However, leaving it unchecked doesn't work: if I restart the phone with it unchecked, the phone acts as if it's docked when it starts again, and I have to go into settings, check the box again, and then uncheck it before the phone behaves. The phone also periodically "forgets" what that I've unchecked the setting (without a reboot), and I have to go check/uncheck it again.
- I've tried clearing all application caches, to no avail.
- I tried clearing the cache partition, to no avail.
- Finally, I tried a factory reset, but the symptoms persisted.
- I've fiddled around with a hand lens and a needle inside the HDMI connector, but couldn't observe any shorted pins and didn't manage to affect the symptoms at all.